# Add tuple to a list of tuples

Tags: python

How can I sum a tuple to a list of tuples such as:

```
>>> a = [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
>>> b = (10, 20, 30)
```

the result being:

```
>>> c 
[(10, 21, 32), (13, 24, 35), (16, 27, 38)]
```

I know this can be easily solved with numpy:

```
>>> import numpy
>>> c = numpy.add(a, b).tolist()
>>> c
[[10, 21, 32], [13, 24, 35], [16, 27, 38]]
```

but I'd rather avoid numpy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one-liner using nested list comprehensions and the magic `zip` to interleave the fixed `b` triplet to add to the iterating element of `a`, no numpy needed:

```
a = [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
b = (10, 20, 30)

c = [tuple([i+j for i,j in zip(e,b)]) for e in a]
print(c)
```

result:

```
[(10, 21, 32), (13, 24, 35), (16, 27, 38)]
```

EDIT: you could drop the `tuple` conversion if not needed:

```
c = [[i+j for i,j in zip(e,b)] for e in a]
```

Comment: a variation of this using `map` and `sum` is `[tuple(map(sum,zip(x,b))) for x in a ]`

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with list comprehension:

```
a = [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
b = (10, 20, 30)
c = [[x + b[i] for i, x in enumerate(y)] for y in a]
```

`c` will be a list of lists, rather than a list of tuples. If that matters, you can do this instead:

```
c = [tuple(x + b[i] for i, x in enumerate(y)) for y in a]
```

Comment: Oops, looks like someone already beat me to it. I'll keep this here to show a way of doing it with `enumerate` rather than `zip` though.

Comment: your solution is faster in python 2 because `zip` builds a list. `enumerate` doesn't. Anyway: good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Define a function to sum two vectors:

```
def sum_vectors(a, b):
    return tuple(sum(z) for z in zip(a, b))
```

Use it to define a function for adding a vector to a list of vectors:

```
def add_vector_to_vectors(v, ws):
    return [sum_vectors(v, w) for w in ws]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> a = [(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]
>>> b = (10, 20, 30)
>>> add_vector_to_vectors(b, a)
[(10, 21, 32), (13, 24, 35), (16, 27, 38)]
```

Comment: You already got some correct answers but I'll keep mine since I find it more readable to break it down in steps.